# Android Java simple compare

Tags: java, android, math, if-statement, sum

I'm trying to do a simple test, namely:

```
double differenza = (d.ele1 - d.ele2);
        double risultato_meno = (differenza - ele5);
        double risultato_piu = (differenza + ele5);
        double comparazione = 0;
        int i1 = Double.compare(ele5, comparazione);

        if (i1 < comparazione){
            tvSaldoTotale.setText(risultato_meno+"");
        }else {
            tvSaldoTotale.setText(risultato_piu+"");
        }
```

but is always calculated the sum, not subtraction.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: could you be more clear?

Comment: Where `ele5` is declared?

Comment: I solved it, thank you. the error was: `double risultato_meno = (differenza - ele5);
         double risultato_piu = (differenza + ele5);`

Answer (score 0):

If your `ele5` is less than zero, then Double.compare will return -1, so the `if` - part will output `risultato_meno` ==  `differenza-ele5` == `differenza + abs(ele5)`.

If your ele5 is zero, then `risultato_meno` and `risultato_piu` will be equal, so you get the same value in both if and else anyway (note that the else part is executed in this case).

If your `ele5` is greater than zero, then Double.compare will return 1, so the `if` - part will output `risultato_piu` ==  `differenza+ele5`.

So basically you're ignoring the sign of ele5, and add it to differenza.

If this is not what you expect, or your program behaves differently from what i described, please give us an example, stating a test case with which variables have which value, what output you expect, and which value your program actually outputs.

Also, try using english variable names if you ask for help here, people will be much less helpful if they don't understand your code because your variable names or strings are incomprehensible.